# convert query to cakephp query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
where concat(`year`,'-',`month`)  BETWEEN '2013-02'  AND '2013-03';
```

how to use this query in cake php's custom query pagination like this way..

```
$conditions = array('concat('Payroll.year','-','Payroll.month')  BETWEEN ? and ?' => array(2013-02, 2013-03));

$staff_list =  $this->Payroll->find("all", array("fields" => array("Payroll.id", "Payroll.month", "Payroll.year"),"conditions"=>$conditions));
```

thank you.

Comment: You did not specify your cakephp version. In cake 2.x you would probably use virtual fields here.

Comment: Is it possible to use the virtual field name in the where condition apart frm the table fields..

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: thanks for ur nice reply....

Comment: $conditions = array('monthyear BETWEEN ? and ?' => array(2013-2, 2013-3));   here monthyear is virtual

Comment: public $virtualFields = array('monthyear' => 'CONCAT(Payroll.year, "-", Payroll.month)')      it is in model field  and the value is show as empty array()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you could do:
**in you model**:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'payroll_date' => 'CONCAT(Payroll.year, " ", Payroll.month)'
);
```

**and in controller**:

```
$staff_list =  $this->Payroll->find("all", array(
  "fields" => array("Payroll.id", "Payroll.month", "Payroll.year"),
  "conditions" => array('Payroll.payroll_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('2013-02', '2013-03'))
));
```